# Converting custom DateTimepicker value to datetime

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a List where i want to find all the rows where a date is equal to `dataTimePicker` the problem is that `dataTimePicker.value` gives DateTime which is what i need but in a wrong format like `8/26/2019` and if i parse it from string to DateTime it returns me that the string is wrong.

I tried parse it to DateTime and convert to date nothing worked

```cs
DateTime da = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimePicker1.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
```

I expect it to return a format like that `ddMMyyyy`

Comment: So, you've got a DateTimepicker and you want to get the `DateTime` as `dd-MM-yyyy` format. Is that right?

Comment: If you've got a DateTime object like you're saying, you can just call `.ToString("ddMMyyyy)` on the object... It makes no sense that you're getting the `DateTime` object and then you're doing all those conversions..

Comment: Yes and after do something like that `.where((DateTime)date_Start == dataTimeicker.Text)`

Comment: Don't use datetimepicker1.text, use datetimepicker1.value. No need to convert string to DateTime. Use myDateTime.ToString(YourFormat) if you want to compare Strings. Use DateTime.Compare() if you want to compare DateTime Objects.

Comment: I need to get it as .text because it converts automatically to a format that i need because the format i have in bd is `ddMMyyyy` not as value returns which is `MMddyyyy`

Comment: Sorry I have updated my comment a second after you replied to it. Read updated comment please.

Comment: `DateTime da = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", null);` That returns me that `System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'` The value `dateTimePicker1.Value {8/26/2019 12:34:08 PM}`

Comment: You have a misconception about what a DateTime object is. DateTime doesn't have a Format. Strings used for presentation have. Take `[DateTimePicker].Value`, as already suggested. Format it as string - for presentation purposes only - if/when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you.

This is just a sample class to use in the example

```
class MyClass
    {
        public DateTime ListDate;
        public String SomeData;
    }
```

Now the comparison becomes

```
foreach(MyClass myClass in myList)
{
     if(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("ddMMyyyy") ==  myClass.ListDate.ToString("ddMMyyyy"))
     {

     }
}
```